# can't find networks on dell inspiron 1501

Tags: wireless, ndiswrapper

Hi installed a clean install of ubuntu 12.04 on a dell inspiron 1501.

according to `sudo lspci -nnv` my wireless card is listed as:

```
Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11b/g WLAN
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1390 WLAN Mini-Card
    Flags: Bus Master, Fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Kernel Driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: wl, ssb
```

It just won't find any wireless networks, i have previously tried to install the windows drivers using `ndiswrapper`

`sudo modprobe ndiswrapper` returns and error `FATAL: Module ndiswrapper is not found`

Can anyone help? Since I'm new to Ubuntu please let me know what extra details you want and I'll update this post with the info

```
lspci -nn -d 14e4:

05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX [14e4:170c] (rev 02)

dmesg | grep b43

[   171.530952] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4311 WLAN found (core revision 10)
[   171.646898] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode5.fw" not found
[   171.646911] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43-open/ucode6.fw" not found
[   171.646917] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this friver version. Please carefully read all instructions on this website
```

Fixed:

Fixed by blacklisting b43 and b43legacy and updating NDISwrapper

Then entering `sudo modprobe ndiswrapper` into terminal

Comment: May I see: lspci -nn -d 14e4:  Thanks!

Comment: @chili555 I have updated the data for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrong driver is installed. Please do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Reboot and you should be all set.

Comment: no such luck :/ the device i mentioned above are still in the same positions

Comment: Please show us: lsmod | grep -e b43 -e ndis -e wl Also: rfkill list all  Thanks.

Comment: first returns nothing and either does the second

Comment: Please do: sudo modprobe b43 and then show me: dmesg | grep b43

Comment: updated for you now, sorry bout the absence

Comment: This indicates that the firmware is still not present! Please try: sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-firmware-nonfree After it's done, reboot and let us hear your results.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9199/discussion-between-chili555-and-puritylake)